# Checking all values in an array and returning false if not string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function (every), taking two arguments, an array, and a callback function. The callback should act as a true/false test, given the contents of the array. If all contents in the array are (for my purposes) a string, then each should return true. If all contents are not a string, then each should return `false.`

Currently I have written:

```
function every(myArray, callback) {
  var myNewArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var added = callback(myArray[i]);
    myNewArray.push(added);
  }
  if (myArray === 'string') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return myNewArray
  }
}

function isTrueOrFalse(string) {
  if (typeof string === 'string') {
     return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
var result = every(
  ['5','test true','truthy statement','stringy'],
  isTrueOrFalse
);
console.log(result);
```

The result is that each logs a boolean value for each index in the array. so `'false'`, `'true'`, `'true'`, `'true'`

However, I need it to simply return one `false` here and break. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new array in `every` doesn't make sense. Check the callback's return value. If false, return false immediately. Otherwise, after the end of the loop, return true.

```js
function every(myArray, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (!callback(myArray[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function isTrueOrFalse(string) {
  return typeof string === 'string';
}
var result = every(['5', 'test true', 'truthy statement', 'stringy'], isTrueOrFalse)
console.log(result)
```